# JDBC JAVAFX date for prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, datepicker

I have a DatePicker set up for JavaFX, i am trying to store the selected date in the date picker to a mySQL table with a date column.

I have as follows, however DatePicker.getValue() returns the selected date as a long.

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, DatePicker.getValue());
```

How do i get the value of datePicker to be in date format eligible to be stored in mySQL date column.

Answer (score 2):

The method [`DatePicker.getValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) returns `java.time.LocalDate`, the method [`PreparedStatement.setDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-) expects a `java.sql.Date`.

You will need to convert the `LocalDate` into a `java.sql.Date`. To do this you can use the method [`java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-):

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(DatePicker.getValue()));
```

If your JDBC driver correctly implements the JDBC 4.2 `java.time` support, then you should also be able to use:

```
preparedStatement.setObject(1, DatePicker.getValue());
```

However as far as I am aware this support is still flaky or non-existent in most JDBC drivers.

As a tip to make your life easier (and not having to wait until someone answers your SO question): When you read (study) the API documentation of classes involved (and those of the return and parameter types) you could have found the answer yourself.